# append data in excel using xml in batch file

Tags: xml, excel, batch-file

Thanks in advance.
I am new to xml coding and would need help to automate a report.

I am using a batch file and calling a sql query from .sql file :

```
set pagesize  0
set linesize 10000
set heading off
set feedback off
set trimspool on
set trimout off
set colsep ','
set verify off

SPOOL D:\iops\1.txt
select '<Row><Cell ss:StyleID="s24"><Data ss:Type="String">' ||count(*) ||'</Data></Cell></Row>' from tx_cdr_summary;
spool off;
exit;
```

and saving the data to %dat%.txt file :
    588468

And then using the xml code in batch file :

```
set /a d=(1%date:~-7,2%-2)-100
set m=%date:~-10,2%
######set m=04
set y=%date:~-4,4%

set dat="%d%.%m%.%y%"

set /P id=Enter USER_NAME: %=%

set /P pass=Enter PASSWORD: %=%
```

type D:\iops\main-header.txt >>Dashboard.xls

```
save %dat%.txt>>D:\iops\%dat%.txt
echo ^<Worksheet ss:Name="%dat%"^>^<Table^> >>Dashboard.xls
echo ^<ss:Column ss:Width="78"/^> >>Dashboard.xls
sqlplus %id%/%pass%@WEST02_PUNE @D:\iops\1.sql ivrstdswimp.
type %dat%.txt>>Dashboard.xls
echo ^</Table^>^</Worksheet^>^</Workbook^> >>Dashboard.xls

pause
exit
```

but when I am querying the same sql tomorrow and I want the data to be with tomorrows date in the same dashboard.xls, it says strict parse error.

I have used this code to call the previous data :
    echo ^^ >>Dashboard.xls
    type %dat%.txt>>Dashboard.xls
    echo ^^ >>Dashboard.xls

```
echo ^<Worksheet ss:Name=%date%^>^<Table^> >>Dashboard.xls
type %date%.txt>>Dashboard.xls
echo ^</Table^>^</Worksheet^> >>Dashboard.xls
```

while doing this I have to define many variable for date and to write the code for all the date i.e. like 30 for a month.

What to be done ?

Thanks